# Content files are not deployed in the Service Fabric package

Tags: azure-service-fabric

We want to deploy a couple of static content files in the service fabric package (configs, metadata). As long as those files are in the root of the package, everything works fine. If we however put them in a subfolder, the files are not included in the package. Is this some kind of bug, is this by design or do we need to configure something?

**Update**

It seems that the problem is in our own custom deployment code (we package and deploy to service fabric ourselves). This is indeed working, as long as the files are marked with *Copy to Output Directory*.

Comment: I assume you're referring to the "PackageRoot" folder in the service project?  That contains a Config sub-folder by default so if you're seeing that the Config folder is getting included in the final package, then that should show that such sub-folders are working.  Can you describe in detail the folder structure you've created?

Comment: I'm not referring to the config subfolder. It is about packaging static files, for instance images, css, javascript or config files. When we create a folder X and put a couple of json files in that folder, the files are not packaged along with the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure that you've updated the project metadata for any such content files so that the "Copy to Output Directory" property is set to "Copy Always" or "Copy if newer".  If the file doesn't show up in the service project's bin folder after executing a normal build, then it for sure won't end up in the generated package.